# Fibonacci numbers properties

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I've verified that

$F_{41} \mod F_{32}= F_{23}$

where $41-32=9$ and $32-9=23$.
I suppose these facts are correlated.

Is there a simple way to show how?

Simpler question: how can I justify that $F_{41} \mod F_{32}$ is a Fibonacci number?

---

I'll tell you the exercise I was working on. Maybe there are other ways I cannot see. I need to know the number of GCD Euclidean (original version, the one with subtractions rather than remainders) algorithm iterations for GCD (F_41, F_32). I computed the ratio between F_41 and F_32 (thanks to Binet's formula) and I got little more than 76. So I said F_41=76*F_32+k. I supposed k a Fibonacci number and thanks to Binet I got the position of k in the Fibonacci series (log_phi was a number very close to 23), so I just sopposed k a Fibonacci number and named it F_23.

$GCD (F_{41},F_{32})=GCD (76F_{32}+F_{23},F_{32})$

F_41=76*F_32+F_23 ... that means that after 76 iterations (in which I subtract F_32 from the bigger number) the GCD algorithm is computing GCD (F_23, F_32). I repeated the assumptions some times and I got the overall number of iterations. I verified it with a simple script and it's correct. The problem is: how can I justify the assumption "k is a fibonacci number", if I have a limited precision calculator and trying to compute the Fibonacci position with Binet formula would only get to a number very close to an integer?

Comment: A positive integer is a Fibonacci number if and only if $5x^2+4$ or $5x^2-4$ is a perfect square. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers

Comment: @vrugtehagel Are you suggesting to actually compute the modulo and verify it belongs to Fibonacci numbers? I supposed there were direct ways...

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting that (since your "simpler question" asked how you could justify that a number is a Fibonacci number) - did you mean that you wish to solve $F_{a+2b}+k\cdot F_{a+b}=F_a$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$? Do you wish to find *all* solutions to that, or just infinte solutions of $a,b,k$ that satisfy it (not necessarily all)?

Comment: @vrugtehagel It would be enough to simply tell why $F_a \mod F_b$ is a Fibonacci number or , if it isn't always true, when this happens to be true..

Comment: Well it's not always true, since $233 \mod 34\equiv 29$

Comment: @vrugtehagel and is there a simple reason why in my example it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35044/discussion-between-vrugtehagel-and-surfer-on-the-fall).

Comment: See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2777282/130022)